# Is .zfproject.xml a must in a Zend Framework project?

Tags: php, zend-framework

1. Is .zfproject.xml a must in a Zend Framework project?
2. What does it do?
3. Is it's location absolute?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using `Zend_Tool` to manage your Zend Framework project, `.zfproject.xml` will contain your application structure state. This is required by `Zend_Tool` (and only by it) to be able to work, e.g. add code to certain parts., generate things, etc.

Quoting ZF Manual on [`Zend_Tool_Project`:](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.project.introduction.html)

> So, for example, if in one command you created a controller, and in the next command you wish to create an action within that controller, Zend_Tool_Project is gonna have to know about the controller file you created so that you can (in the next action), be able to append that action to it.

I am not sure if Zend_Tool can be configured to use a different path to `.zfproject.xml`. My suggestion would be to leave it untouched. It's a hidden file anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add, the zfproject.xml is not needed if you don't use Zend_Tool.

So it's not a must. Personally, I manage all my zf projects more or less without a command line and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Basically if your going to use Zend_Tool, stick with it. Zend Tool doesn't like it when you create MVC manually. Its just another layer of abstraction that you can probably live without.

Answer (score 1):

I am using zend framework 1.10. Whenever I create a action using zf tool it re-indents the code in the controller file and removes some function closing brackets. It is kind of buggy, so will not be using it from now on.

Comment: I stopped using the zf command line tool for the same reason. Would be glad if there's some fix to that problem.

Comment: it would be better to report this as an issue here http://framework.zend.com/issues/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I'm now convinced that zf command is useless, as it doesn't recognize my custom library path, and stopping me from adding actions to controllers that extends my custom controllers, so, end of the road for the zend tool