# custom .zfproject.xml file

Tags: zend-framework, project

Yall:

I'm trying to squeeze the Zend Framework into my ISP securely.

My ISP pretty much requires me to put much of the stack in a /private directory
in my HTDOCS Home.

So, it looks like this

```
/index.php 
/private/application/configs
/private/application/controllers
/private/application/bootstrap.php

...
```

I tried editing the .zfproject.xml so indicate this, but ZF.bat/ZF.sh seems 
to ignore this.

Anyone had any success with this type of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you should just set up the directory like this:
/private/MyProject/application

DONE! No need to modify the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'll be using [Zend_Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.project.introduction.html) you won't need zfproject.xml.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544263/is-zfproject-xml-a-must-in-a-zend-framework-project) talks more about it.