# what is the significance of .zfproject.xml file

Tags: zend-framework

Usually i create controller and rest of the work (actions method) and view files i do manually. does .zfproject.xml file has any significance?

Comment: Taking a guess: it probably could be used as a boilerplate for navigation or so. It's fairly impractical though, since it doesn't account for manually added stuff, or automatically added and then manually deleted f.e. controllers.

Comment: It's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544263/is-zfproject-xml-a-must-in-a-zend-framework-project

Comment: i do all my work without zfproject.xml, may be it will be useful in future release for build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zfproject.xml` is used by `Zend_Tool` to store information about created controllers, actions, etc. within project - but only these created by using `zf` command.

Comment: No, if you don't use `zf` tool you can get rid of file `zf.project`. But look at the link provided at question comments by @chelmertz

Comment: This is the only use I see in the zfproject.xml